# In a backbonejs view, do keypress/keyup/keydown events work only with input and not other elements?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

What would be the best way to detect `onkeypress` event on a div in backbonejs view?
Currently putting it in the events is not working,

```
events: {
 "keypress div#xyz": "myFunction" 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that keyboard events are sent only to the element that has focus (for example a form input) and are not bubbled to container elements. http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

You should bind it to the exact element(s) in which text can be entered.

```
events: { "keypress #xyz input" : "myFunction" }
```

Comment: Adding a `tabindex` to a div should allow it to get focus... if you don't want it in the tab ordering I think you can do `tabindex="-1"`. I don't know if that affects "key" events, though.